# What role do studies say that "rest" plays in tennis elbow healing?

Tags: treatment, clinical-study, epicondylitis

I was recently diagnosed with tennis elbow and the ortho ordered 'rest' and NSAIDS.  Limited (programming) work, and no more gaming or cards, and only necessary phone usage, as well as no heavy labor at all with that arm.  He gave a very good explanation of why rest should work to help heal.

Though he also suggested a steroid injection and gave a very good reason that should work, despite studies showing little to no effect at 52 weeks compared to no active treatment, and despite growing concern about steroid shots causing long term joint damage.  The point being that sometimes things we (even professionals) reasonably think *should* work, do not always end up working when we observe reality.  This got me to thinking about the assumptions we may be making about rest.

I've seen quite a few studies comparing steroid shots, prolotherapy, PRP injections, HA injections, and comparisons of those to rest & NSAIDS (as a control group).  However, I haven't actually come across any studies that look at whether healing and long term outcomes vary with different levels of rest, or if rest really plays a role at all.

Has this ever been clinically studied?  Do we have any actual data or statistics on what role rest plays in the healing of tennis elbow?